Adding attributes to entire c-file instead of specific function
Hi I was trying to add  the attribute __attribute__((section(".protected"))) to my whole c file. My  temporary solution was to just give this attribute to main() and put all the variables and functions in main. Is there any way to add this attribute to the whole c file?
This section is declared in the linker file.
Thanks in advance, jip.
